# How to Customize the Filter in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to customize my filter in activeadmin panel for applications panel.
currently i have a filter like this.
[image: Current i have filter like this]

and want the filter like this

[image]

i do the code for this as follow

For add category element in filter i do as follow code.

There is 3 tables called

1. applications
2. categories
3. application_categories

and i want the filter data from application_categories as per selection on category from filter.

Structure of tables as  follow.

1. applications table :

   1. id
   2. name
   3. status
   4. developer_id
   5. version
   6. language_id ,etc...
2. categories table

   1. id
   2. name
   3. parent_id
3. application_categories table

   1. id
   2. application_id
   3. category_id

In activeadmin resource file
app/admin/applications.rb file code

filter :status, :as => :select, :collection => ["pending", "approved", "declined"]
filter :featured, :as => :select
filter :developer, :collection => proc {(Developer.all).map{|d| [d.company_name, d.id]}}
filter :category , :collection => proc {(Category.all).map{|c| [c.name,c.id]}}
filter :name
filter :version
filter :tags

In application model file
in model app/models/application.rb

belongs_to :developer
belongs_to :bundle
belongs_to :license
belongs_to :language
belongs_to :category

has_many :application_categories, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :categories, :through => :application_categories

It’s display category element in filter panel, but when we select any category and click on filter it’s generate an error as shown below :

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'applications.category_id' in 'on clause': SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT count_column) FROM (SELECT  `applications`.`id` AS count_column FROM `applications` LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `applications`.`category_id` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 32 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count

Answer (score 0):

In `app/admin/applications.rb`:

```
filter :categories
```

In `app/models/application.rb`: delete `belongs_to :category`

If it doesn't work, you have to update your ActiveAdmin gem: `bundle update`

Comment: I re-write the code as per your suggestion and update the bundle, but it's still not working. and even more the dropdown list of the categories is also not display in admin panel.

Comment: No, I didn't get any error message. it execute as it is.